# Asp.Net C#: Add GridView in jQuery Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create a function to show a DataGridView dynamically, let's code:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

GridView grid = new GridView();
grid.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

foreach (GridColumnTemplate grdColumnTemplate in parameters.ColumnsTemplate)
{
    BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
    boundField.DataField = grdColumnTemplate.ValueFieldName;
    boundField.HeaderText = grdColumnTemplate.HeaderText;
    grid.Columns.Add(boundField);
}

grid.DataSource = parameters.DataSource;

div.Controls.Add(grid);

Controls.Add(div);

String cmd = "<script language=JavaScript> ShowGrid('{0}'); </script>\n";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowGrid",string.Format(cmd,div.ID));
```

This is the ShowGrid function:

```
function ShowGrid(idDiv) {
    var modal = $(idDiv).dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false
    });
    modal.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
}
```

But, when the code is executed, I have an error saying to input the gridview inside a "runat=server" container.
I tryed by code to do this, but without sucess.

Help me plz!!

Comment: can you post your ShowGrid function in js?

Comment: Yes, sure! I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it, in the following manner:

```
<a href="javascript:loadGridOnClick()">Load</a>
<div class="Modal">
     <asp:GridView id="grdExample" runat="server">
          // Grid Logic
     </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

We have our front-end structure, now to populate our Grid:

```
function loadGridOnClick() {
     $.ajax({
          url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Services/GetGridForSample.ashx") %>',
          type: 'POST',
          data { ... } // If we have any data to populate our Grid.
          success: function () {
               // Our return object.
          }
     });

}
```

Once you call the service via Ajax, you would simply write your backend code to populate the Grid with the correct data.  Then you would simply `DataSource` and `DataBind`.  The other approach would be to simply only have our `<div class="Modal">`, then you could return a collection of your `Object` and place in your own structure.

That would be the approach I would take, otherwise you may fight with the `Postback` and state information.

Comment: but we want to use this function to all pages, could I use it too?

Comment: Sure, the service could abstract based on a QueryString.  That would allow the Grid to constantly change.